# Why is the GULO pseudo gene expressed in humans?

Tags: human-genetics, enzymes, molecular-evolution

The GULO pseudo gene is being expressed in humans according to [Genecards](https://www.genecards.org/cgi-bin/carddisp.pl?gene=GULOP#expression).

Why is this still taking place after tens of millions of years since then gene lost the capacity to encode for a functional enzyme?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest thinking about this from a different direction — something like: "What selection pressure is there for loss of expression of the GULO pseudogene?"

When thinking about that question note that the [expression level is very low](https://www.gtexportal.org/home/gene/GULOP) (less than 1 transcript in a million in the tissue with the highest level of expression.

In general, evolution is messy and I think your null hypothesis should be that this as a [vestigial trait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vestigiality).

In other words, unless you can show that there is a significant cost for the low level of expression seen from this pseudogene there is nothing to explain.